# Elmah backup exception logging

Tags: elmah

I have set up elmah to log exceptions on my SQL server. Is there any way to define a fallback mechanism if the SQL server fails. I would like elmah to start logging to xml files if the sql server is inaccessible. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: +1 I am looking for the exact same thing.

Comment: +1 I would love something like this as well.

Comment: It seems that ELMAH does not support a fallback. see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391494/what-to-do-if-elmah-cant-reach-the-database-to-log-an-exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391494/what-to-do-if-elmah-cant-reach-the-database-to-log-an-exception)

Answer (score 0):

Elmah doesn't yet support fallback or concurrent logging locations.

[What to do if Elmah can't reach the database to log an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391494/what-to-do-if-elmah-cant-reach-the-database-to-log-an-exception)

Answer (score 0):

I released a composite errorlog which address exactly this issue.
You can install it via [Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/Elmah.FallbackErrorLog/) or copy it from [sources](https://github.com/eric-b/Elmah.FallbackErrorLog/) into your projects.

More details in my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14703724/249742).